# How to get 403 error message in Laravel Inertia as flash message?

Tags: vuejs3, laravel-9, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

Laravel 9 Jestream + Inertia + VUE3.

In the authorization policy, I return an error with the text

```
return Response::deny(trans('error'));
```

On the front, the Inertia modal window opens and I see the error text.

I added processing to Handler

```
 if ($response->status() === 403) {

     session()->flash('flash', [
         'bannerStyle' => 'danger',
         'banner' => $e->getMessage(),
     ]);

     return back();

 }
```

Now the Inertia modal window is not shown and I see the error text as a flash message. BUT.
Now I don't get 403 errors if I made a request without inertia (axios library).

If I remove this code, returning 403 errors in axios requests works correctly (in vue as text). But with inertia requests, I again see a full-screen modal with a huge number 403. And I want to receive a small flash message. How can I do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably check if the request is from Inertia or not. (covered in an answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75934003/3650979 )

In your handler you might do something like:

```php
if ($request->inertia() && $request->expectsJson() {
    if ($response->status() === 403) {
    }
}
// ## not tested ##
```