# Laravel Inertia - check if request comes from Intertiajs components or API

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, inertiajs

I am wondering if there is a way to check on the backend (Laravel) if the request (for example GET /posts) comes from an Inertia frontend or from other source (like Postman API).

For now it seems if I wanted to make a public API for shared routes (like CRUD of Posts model), I would have to make separate routes, because the controller returns a server-side rendered Vuejs component.

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->authorize('viewAny', Post::class);

    if(request()->isInertiaRequest()) {      //<- check if the request is API or Vuejs Inertia frontend
        return inertia('Posts/Index', [
            'posts' => PostResource::collection($this->postService->index()),
        ]);
    }
    return PostResource::collection($this->postService->index());
}
```

I feel like writing separate API and Inertia routes would go against DRY, as the returned data would be the same resource.

Answer (score 2):

the following line of code would check if the request is from API for your case

```
if(!$request->inertia() && $request->expectsJson())
```